# Simultaneous confindence intervals for a normal distribution in R

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Say $x$ is $p$ dimensional and normal distributed with covariance matrix $V$ and zero means. Is there function in some R-package that computes $p$ intervals $\{I_1, I_2,...,I_p\}$ such that the density integrates to $0.95$ over their cartesian product $I_1\times I_2\times\ ...\times\ I_p$, while the lebesgue measure of the cartesian product is minimal?

Comment: Are you asking about confidence intervals (of what?), or about highest density intervals?

Comment: @Tim Neither specifically. As to this question why does it matter?